# Creating folders in Azure DataLake gen 2 with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-cli

Is it possible to create a folder in Azure DataLake gen 2 with Azure CLI?

Something like with this code:

```
dls fs create --account my-storage-account --folder  --path my-folder
```

Or are there some other tools which could help to automate creation of DataLake gen2 with folders and role assignments?

Comment: @GeorgeChen, seems REST API is the only option I can use now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could know the tools limits for now is not supported from this doc: [Programming interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#programming-interfaces) and this [Known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#support-for-other-blob-storage-features).

[image]

[image]

Fro now the tools you could use:

1. [AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json)(Earlier versions of AzCopy such as AzCopy v8.1, are not supported)
2. [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-explorer)
3. [Azure Data Lake Store REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer this question but I was able to create an empty folder using cli

1. az login --service-principal --username  --password  --tenant
2. az storage fs directory create -n <name_of_folder_to_be_created> -f <container_name>/ --account-name <account_name>

the service principal should have valid scops and use the latest az CLI

output was:

```
{
  "content_length": 0,
  "continuation": null,
  "date": "<removed>",
  "etag": "\"<removed>\"",
  "last_modified": "2021-05-11T18:32:03+00:00",
  "request_id": "<removed>",
  "version": "<removed>"
}
```